# How to get your Custom Domain Name if you have Mydomain enabled - using Apex?

Tags: apex, mydomain

I have registered my domain in Salesforce org
I wanted to know how could I get domain name using apex.

Suppose my domain is `XXXX-dev-ed`, I know we have [URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_URL_getSalesforceBaseUrl)
but what I am looking for is

1. Which method would return me my domain name such that I could add condition in my method like

   ```
   if(DomainIsEnabled){
      //Append Doamin Name and construct URL
   }else{
      //construct URL using SF instance and by using URL methods.
   }
   ```
2. How to check if user has register a Domain in SF org?

I checked `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()` but that returned me

```
XXXX-dev-ed--c.na31.visual.force.com
```

I could add parsing logic for string to just get `XXXX-dev-ed` from above string like `System.URL.getSalesforceBaseURL().getHost().split('--c.')[0]` , but problem will occure if user has not registered any custom domain.

please advice if there is any best way available to directly get registered SF domain name and way to check if user has registered a custom domain

I believe Salesforce must be storing this information somewhere not sure if can access this using SOQL or by using some other-way.

> I want to construct URL when user has registered a Domain and when
>   user has not registered.

Custom Domain -->
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can run SOQL on [organization object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_organization.htm) which will return you instance name

```
Select InstanceName from Organization
```

To get domain details you can query [Domain object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_domain.htm)

```
SELECT Domain FROM Domain
```

Consideration

- Customer Portal users can’t access this object.
- To view this object,
  you must have the “View Setup and Configuration” permission.
- Site.com
  Publisher users have read-only API access to the Domain and
  DomainSite objects.
- Class should be defined as without sharing keyword.

Comment: that will give me value like NA31,na11 or whatever the SF instance available, I want to find registered domain name.

Comment: for that you can query domain object

Comment: SELECT Domain FROM Domain will return domain registered for your Froce.com site, is there any way using which I can retrieve my custom Domain

Comment: I want information regarding how we can retrieve our custom domain name !

Comment: Also how we can check if user has registered custom domain Name.

Comment: I found one nice answer here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/14532/get-visualforce-url-with-custom-domains-turned-on

Comment: but still problem remains  "how we can check if user has registered custom domain Name" !!

Comment: I am also checking

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, the best answer to this, I believe, is to use the getOrgDomainURL() method of the URL class, which returns the canonical URL for your org (https://**MyDomainName**.my.salesforce.com). That's because this method will always return the my domain base URL, rather than returning different hosts based on the context (Lightning, VF, Communities, etc)

See: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_url.htm#apex_System_Url_getOrgDomainUrl

`URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()` would return the custom domain URL, if one exists, otherwise it would return the instance name. You'd still need to parse/split/substring the response to pull out the my domain/instance, and then you would then implement logic on your end to determine whether or not custom domains are enabled based on the response from this method. If you only receive an instance, they do not have a custom domain.